# Pandas combine column values for similar rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with similar rows with a unique column value.  If any of the rows have a duplicate combination of values, I need to concatenate the unique values into a column for each row.

Sample Data

```
| program | subject | course | title |
|:------- |:------- |:------ |:----- |
|music    | eng     | 101    | 000   |
|music    | math    | 101    | 123   |
|music    | eng     | 102    | 000   |
|music    | math    | 101    | 456   |
|art      | span    | 201    | 123   |
|art      | hst     | 101    | 000   |
|art      | span    | 201    | 456   |
|art      | span    | 202    | 000   |
```

Desired Data

```
| program | subject | course | title.   |
|:------- |:------- |:------ |:-----    |
|music    | eng     | 101    | 000      |
|music    | math    | 101    | 123-456  |
|music    | eng     | 102    | 000      |
|music    | math    | 101    | 456-123  |
|art      | span    | 201    | 123-456  |
|art      | hst     | 101    | 000      |
|art      | span    | 201    | 456-123  |
|art      | span    | 202    | 000      |
```

The first three columns in the 2nd and 4th as well as the 5th and 7th rows match.  I want to concatenate the titles so each row contains a combination of titles for matching rows.

Comment: This assumes there would only be 2 duplicates? What if there are 3?

Comment: Right now, there are only two duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform):

```py
df['title'] = df.groupby(
    ['program', 'subject', 'course'], as_index=False, sort=False
)['title'].transform('-'.join)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  program subject  course    title
0   music     eng     101      000
1   music    math     101  123-456
2   music     eng     102      000
3   music    math     101  123-456
4     art    span     201  123-456
5     art     hst     101      000
6     art    span     201  123-456
7     art    span     202      000
```

Comment: For what it looks like its worth, this should suffice ..

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if this problem required the extra computation time to enforce the ordering in the lists like you did. Since the primary request seems to be just "concatenate the unique values into a column for each row"

Comment: Yes and with just 2 duplicates I guess one can live with it :) no need of complicating

Answer (score 2):

Experimenting with [`networkx`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) to match the exact expected output, probably overengineered:

```
import networkx as nx

u = df.assign(k=df.groupby(['program','subject','course']).ngroup())
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(u,'title','k',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
l =[f"{a}-{''.join(b.difference([a]))}".rstrip("-") 
 for a,b in zip(u['title'],u['k'].map(lambda x: nx.ancestors(G,x)))]
df['new_title'] = l
```

---

```
print(df)

  program subject course title new_title
0   music     eng    101   000       000
1   music    math    101   123   123-456
2   music     eng    102   000       000
3   music    math    101   456   456-123
4     art    span    201   123   123-456
5     art     hst    101   000       000
6     art    span    201   456   456-123
7     art    span    202   000       000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two data frames, then drop duplicate rows

```
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)

# dropping duplicate values
result.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
```